# Logical Expressions in C misunderstanding

Tags: c, logical-operators

So, I was writing some code and I was getting an unexpected output in one part of my program which disrupted the entire system.

I managed to extract and simplify the problem to a basic logical expression. Let's say:

```
int i = 1, j = 1, k = 0;

printf("%d\n", ++i || ++j && k);
printf("%d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k);

return 0;
```

The output for this program is:

`1`

`2` `1` `0`

I am thinking that the value of `j` was not incremented to `2` due to the short circuit nature of the `||` operator. However I am confused how the value of the first `"%d"` is `1`. Shouldn't the value of `k` be non-zero for the `&&` statement to return `1`? Or isn't this statement executed at all since `++i || ++j` is not `0` and thus returns a `1`?

- I know that `&&` is a logical *and*, and  *expr1* && *expr2* has the value 1 if values of *expr1* && *expr2* are **both** non-zero.

Any clarifications would be appreciated and please excuse the basic nature of this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`.
(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B )
so

```
++i || ++j && k
```

is

```
++i || (++j && k)
```

and `||` shortcircuits if the first operator is truthy, as per [6.5.14p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.14p4) .

If you're on `gcc` or `clang` and compile your code with `-Wall`, the compiler will nudge you to put those parentheses there. It's probably a good idea to heed that advice, as some people get confused by the precedences (I hear).

Comment: unfortunately I am using VS2015. I will soon be looking to start using `gcc`. I am assuming that you would suggest doing so ? I have always used VS since it is recommended for students... (or so I thought)

Comment: @Rizzo I think gcc is definitely a great compiler, both in terms of developer convenience and speed of generated code, but use whatever you like. ;)

Answer (score 3):

From the C Standard (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 3 The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
>   unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

This expression

```
++i || ++j && k
```

is equivalent to

```
++i || ( ++j && k )
```

and according to the quote from the Standard the expression returns integer value 1 because `++i` is not equal to zero. The subexpression `( ++j && k )` is not evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

`++i || ++j && k` is evaluate to 1 (true) because i equals 2 (++1), (++j && k) isn't evaluated because short circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Operators precedence. `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

Your expression is the same as: `++i || (++j && k)`

`++i` is `TRUE`, the parenthesis is not evaluated anymore.